# Make particles interact with a flip-fluids simulation

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I want to make a particles from the particle system to interact and create ripples on the fluid simulation. Again I'm using flip fluids. I tried setting the emitter as an obstacle and tried to set the object(of the particles) to an obstacle too but I had no luck with both.

Need help ( :

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd. I believe mantaflow doesn't support using particles as effectors for collision, only for smoke inflow. Are you familiar with the new simulation branch for geometry nodes? You could potentially make your own basic particle system, realize the instances at the end, and use it as an effector in the liquid sim. I haven't tried it, but it should work. Mantaflow does support animated meshes, as collision objects.

A superior fluid system is the FLIP FLUIDS Addon. It's not free, but it is open source, so if you're willing to compile it yourself, you can get it for free. It might support particles, but I'm not certain.

Keep in mind, if you've got a static mesh or fluid surface and you want to create small ripples, you'd use Dynamic Paint. However, it loses the ripple movement when the underlying mesh changes, especially the vertex count.

It's kinda disappointing that Blender's fluid system is still somewhat limited, but iam hoping the upcoming simulation nodes will bring some improvements.

Comment: Well said, that's what I did btw used dynamic paint and it was actually more preformance friendly.